# Getting position of native element relative to viewport via Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, dom

I'm using @ViewChild to access a native DOM element in my template. I want to figure out where in the viewport this element is.

```
this.myElement.nativeElement.???
```

I believe I need to get a few data points here to figure this out.

I can get the height of the viewport with:

```
window.innerHeight
```

But I'm stumped on how to find the position of `myElement` in relation to said viewport with Angular.

Comment: What about [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve the position (X,Y) of an HTML element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element)

Answer (score 3):

Use [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

```
constructor(private ele: ElementRef<HTMLElement>)
{

}

// scrolls an element into view if it's too close to the top of the screen
scrollIntoView() 
{
      var bounds = this.ele.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();

      if (bounds.top < 50)
      {
          window.scrollBy(0, -50 + bounds.top );
      }
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend creating a ScrollService for stuff like this that injects the element ref - then your component injects the scroll service and calls `scrollIntoView()` on it. #dry